# Laptop won't boot and can't see partition

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I am running Ubuntu 10.10. on an Acer Aspire laptop alongside windows 7. I left my laptop on the battery which clearly ran out- and now neither windows nor ubuntu will load (I am currently running ubuntu off a USB stick). On the USB stick I can see the windows partition and access the files, but I can't even see the ubuntu partition- I don't think it is mounted.

In the device manager I have no option to mount it, I can format it but when I try, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a terminal:

```
dmesg | grep sda
```

Can you access the hard disk?

```
sudo cfdisk /dev/sda
```

Maybe your ubuntu partition is already mounted:

```
mount | grep sd
```

Comment: [ 4076.613216] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)